# How to achieve Card-Title behavior on different screen sizes in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, user-interface, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am new to web designing, Is it possible to change `font-size` of **card-title** and **card image size** according to **different screen sizes** in bootstrap 4. Because when it come for small screen size its too large with.

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10">
  <img class="card-img-top-a mx-auto d-block mt-5" src="img/a.png"> 
    <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-5 font-weight-bold">Pixel perfect design</h5>
    <p class="card-text px-auto text-justify">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10"> 
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto d-block mt-5" src="img/b.png">  
  <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-5 font-weight-bold">Design Tageted</h5>
  <p class="card-text px-auto text-justify">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10"> 
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto d-block mt-5" src="img/c.png">  
  <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-5 font-weight-bold">Finalize a FSL</h5>
  <p class="card-text px-auto text-justify">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius</p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code example for how I manage `p{}`.

So Do I have to do same thing for `card-title` or if there a other way of doing it ?

```
@media (min-width: 0px) { p{font-size: 0.7rem;}}
@media (min-width: 576px) { p{font-size: 0.6rem;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) { p {font-size: 0.8rem;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) { p {font-size: 0.8rem;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { p {font-size: 1rem;}}
```

And What should I do for images for different screen sizes?

```
.card-img-top{
  width: 80px;
  height:80px;
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. But you have to adjust the size of text and title and but this will work for you sure

```css
.card-img-top {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

@media (min-width: 0px) {
  .responsive-text {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }
  
  .responsive-title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .responsive-text {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
  }
  
  .responsive-title {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .responsive-text {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .responsive-title {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .responsive-text {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .responsive-title {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .responsive-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .responsive-title {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10">
  <img class="card-img-top-a mx-auto d-block mt-5" src="img/a.png">
  <p class="card-title text-center mt-5 font-weight-bold responsive-title">Pixel perfect design</p>
  <p class="card-text px-auto text-justify responsive-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10">
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto d-block mt-5" src="img/b.png">
  <p class="card-title text-center mt-5 font-weight-bold responsive-title">Design Tageted</p>
  <p class="card-text px-auto text-justify responsive-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius</p>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10">
  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto d-block mt-5" src="img/c.png">
  <p class="card-title text-center mt-5 font-weight-bold responsive-title">Finalize a FSL</p>
  <p class="card-text px-auto text-justify responsive-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `<p>` tag in both tittle and text but you have to difine the class name to that tag and you have to insert the size you want in that.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Its work nicely :) 
Do u have idea about this png images responsiveness ? Its not resizing properly according to screen size

Comment: If you want to resize your png image and make it responsive then add one class in `<img>` tag and after that add that class name to css and give the `height` and `width` as per you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well as `rem` works relative to the root element of document i.e. `html`...and by default browsers have

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

So with this concept try to change only the `html` font value not all elements font...

```css
html {
  font: 16px Verdana
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>foo</h1>
<h2>bar</h2>
```

A **[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/egko12fa/)** for editing